# RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn when start trainer.fit()

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

### description

When I launch the script, The code runs well after Validation sanity check. The error occurred when it started training.

### key package version

```
transformers             4.32.1
pytorch==1.13.1 torchvision==0.14.1 torchaudio==0.13.1 pytorch-cuda=11.6
pytorch-lightning        2.0.3
```

### My train function using pytorch-lightning

```py
def train(args):

    ···
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        devices=1,
        accelerator="gpu",
        max_epochs=cfg.hyperparam.train_epochs,
        check_val_every_n_epoch=2,
    )

    ···

    val_df = data[data["fold"] == cfg.hyperparam.fold_num].reset_index(drop=True)
    train_df = data[data["fold"] != cfg.hyperparam.fold_num].reset_index(drop=True)
    logger.info(
        "load dataset in {}, using dataset: {}".format(
            cfg.hyperparam.input_dir, cfg.dataset.dataset_type
        )
    )
    mydatasets = Customdata(train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, cfg=cfg)
    logger.info(
        "prepare model in {}, the model type is {}".format(
            cfg.hyperparam.models_ckpt_dir, cfg.model.backbone_type
        )
    )
    model = FeedBackModel(len_train_dataset=len(train_df), cfg=cfg)
    train_dl = mydatasets.train_dataloader()
    val_dl = mydatasets.val_dataloader()
    logger.info("start training")

    # ------- error occurred -----

    trainer.fit(
        model=model,
        train_dataloaders=train_dl,
        val_dataloaders=val_dl,
    )
```

### Error information

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/data1/whd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/data1/whd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/data1/whd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/data1/whd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/data1/whd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/data1/whd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/data1/whd/Feedback/src/train.py", line 198, in <module>
    main()
  File "/data1/whd/Feedback/src/train.py", line 175, in main
    train(args)
  File "/data1/whd/Feedback/src/train.py", line 120, in train
    trainer.fit(
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 531, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 42, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 570, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 975, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1018, in _run_stage
    self.fit_loop.run()
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 201, in run
    self.advance()
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 354, in advance
    self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 133, in run
    self.advance(data_fetcher)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 218, in advance
    batch_output = self.automatic_optimization.run(trainer.optimizers[0], kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 185, in run
    self._optimizer_step(kwargs.get("batch_idx", 0), closure)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 260, in _optimizer_step
    call._call_lightning_module_hook(
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 140, in _call_lightning_module_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1256, in optimizer_step
    optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 155, in step
    step_output = self._strategy.optimizer_step(self._optimizer, closure, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 225, in optimizer_step
    return self.precision_plugin.optimizer_step(optimizer, model=model, closure=closure, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 114, in optimizer_step
    return optimizer.step(closure=closure, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 140, in wrapper
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py", line 439, in step
    loss = closure()
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 101, in _wrap_closure
    closure_result = closure()
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 140, in __call__
    self._result = self.closure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 135, in closure
    self._backward_fn(step_output.closure_loss)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 232, in backward_fn
    call._call_strategy_hook(self.trainer, "backward", loss, optimizer)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 287, in _call_strategy_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 200, in backward
    self.precision_plugin.backward(closure_loss, self.lightning_module, optimizer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 67, in backward
    model.backward(tensor, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1046, in backward
    loss.backward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 488, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/data1/whd/.conda/envs/commonlit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 197, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

### Other code blocks

```py
# pl_model
class FeedBackModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, len_train_dataset, cfg) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.model = InnerModel(cfg)
        self.len_train_dataset = len_train_dataset
        self.test_labels = []
    
        ···

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, targets = batch
        inputs["input_ids"] = torch.squeeze(inputs["input_ids"], dim=1)
        inputs["attention_mask"] = torch.squeeze(inputs["attention_mask"], dim=1)
        loss = self.model(inputs, targets)
        # loss = self.model.loss(output, targets)
        if self.cfg.hyperparam.use_wandb:
            wandb.log({"train_loss": loss.item()})

        self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

# InnerModel
class InnerModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cfg) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.backbone, self.tokenizer, self.model_config = get_backbone(cfg)
        self.tokenizer.model_max_length = cfg.hyperparam.max_seq_len
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(self.model_config.hidden_size, 1)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(self.model_config.hidden_size, 1)
        self.loss = get_criterion(cfg.criterion.criterion_type)
        self.pooling = None
        # self.len_train_dataset = len_train_dataset
        logger.info("using pooling layer: {}".format(cfg.model.pooling_type))
        self.pooling = get_pooling(cfg, self.model_config)

    def forward(self, inputs, target=None):
        input_ids = inputs["input_ids"]
        attention_mask = inputs["attention_mask"]
        output = self.backbone(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        features = self.pooling(inputs, output)
        content = self.linear1(features)
        wording = self.linear2(features)
        features = torch.cat([content, wording], dim=1)
        if target is not None:
            loss = self.loss(features, target)
            return loss
        else:
            return features
```

To located what the reason of this error. I did some experiments texted below:

```py
# To test the InnerModel part
def debug(args):
    seed_everything()

    cfg = get_config(args.config_dir)
    cfg = dictionary_to_namespace(cfg)
    cfg.hyperparam.use_wandb = args.use_wandb
    cfg.hyperparam.wandb_trial_name = args.trial_name
    model = InnerModel(cfg)
    input_ids = torch.randint(0, 100, (2, 50))
    attn = torch.ones(2, 50)
    target = torch.randn(2, 2)
    inputs = {"input_ids": input_ids, "attention_mask": attn}
    pl_model = FeedBackModel(10, cfg)
    pl_model.training_step((inputs, target), 0)
```

Then I call this function in main, and neglect `train(args)`.

```py
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--config_dir",
        type=str,
        default="./config/comlitConfig_v2.yml",
        help="the config file you want to use",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--use_wandb", type=bool, default=False, help="whether to use wandb"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--trial_name", type=str, default=None, help="what name is this trial in wandb"
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #train(args)
    debug(args)
```

It didn't raise any error
Then I set a breaking point on line `result = model(inputs, target)` and step into it. Then I step to line `if target is not None`.

```py
class InnerModel(nn.Module):

    ···

    def forward(self, inputs, target=None):
        input_ids = inputs["input_ids"]
        attention_mask = inputs["attention_mask"]
        output = self.backbone(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        features = self.pooling(inputs, output)
        content = self.linear1(features)
        wording = self.linear2(features)
        features = torch.cat([content, wording], dim=1)
        if target is not None:
            loss = self.loss(features, target)
            return loss
        else:
            return features
```

and enter 2 command in debug console on VSCode

```py
    loss2 = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(features,target)
    loss2.backward()
```

And there is no error occurred. Then I neglect `debug` and call `train` in main. and do the same operation above, error occurred when I enter `loss2.backward()`, which is the same error. But I can't figure out why it happends.

I also have tried to find some solution on web. But it seems that no solution matches my situation. At last  I add a line when initializing my trainer, here is the code block

```py
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        devices=1,
        accelerator="gpu",
        max_epochs=cfg.hyperparam.train_epochs,
        check_val_every_n_epoch=2,
        # new line
        precision=16
    )
```

And it magically works, train section begins, and run well. But I still don't know why it works and why the error occurred.

If you have insight of this problem, please free to comment. I was confused for a long time by this problem, and would be appreciate if you could answer my confusion.